# Giant SLR1 Hookless Rims Issues

Tags: tire, wheels, puncture, giant

I recently purchased a Giant Propel Advanced Pro and the bike comes with Giant's new tubeless-ready SLR1 hookless rims with Cadex tyres. Since purchasing, I have had a few punctures and have decided to run the wheelset with a tube. One huge problem I am facing with these rims compared to others I have had is the sheer amount of force required to take the tyre on and off the rim in the case of a puncture. Even once I have removed the tyre from the rim, to ensure it becomes seated, I have to pump it up to >120psi (something that I can't do with a hand pump on the side of the road).

I have considered getting a new set of tyres to see whether the same problem persists but I was wondering if anyone else has had the same issues as me and has been able to fix it. I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter as I am getting rather frustrated with getting punctures and being unable to fix it whilst out on the road.

Comment: Can you clarify if you know the standard procedure of pushing the beads into the rim well? You may already know this, but not everyone does

Comment: What was the reason the tubeless wouldn't seal?  Did you have sealant in the tyre?  What width are the tyres and at what pressure do you run them?   120 PSI seems a lot for modern ~28mm, I'd expect that kind of pressure in 19mm cheesecutters or track bikes used on indoor velodromes.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Yes I am aware of this

Comment: @Criggie Where I am the roads are pretty rough and the tubeless, as you said, wouldn’t seal. I had sealant in the tyre and I am currently running 25mm tyres with a tube at 100psi. I need to put 120psi in to make sure the tyre seats initially. When I was running tubeless I think I was running 80-90psi. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Hookless rims are rated to a max pressure of only 72 psi per the ETRTO standard. I would recommend not exceeding that. I think you should be able to get the tire seated with less pressure? I do inflate my tubeless canister to 130-140 psi, but that doesn’t produce a tire pressure of 130-140.

Comment: @WeiwenNg would you recommend trying tubeless again with a lower pressure?

Comment: Have you check Giant's calculator (https://www.giant-bicycles.com/global/tire-pressure). Assuming your rims are 19,4 mm inner width and you are running 25 mm, that would be 80 PSI for a light (65 kg) rider and 100 PSI for their maximum system weight of 129 kg. So, your tubeless pressures of 80-90 PSI were absolutely fine - not sure how this translates to tubes. Also wondering about the many punctures because for example a road.cc review characterizes the Gavia Course 1 (?) as a durable tire with good puncture protection.

Comment: @DoNuT Getting punctures I am completely fine with. It's just a matter of techniques to get the tyre on and off the rim after a puncture to, for example, replace the inner tube. I'm finding it near impossible to do without some wrench to grip onto the tyre and then pull off the tyre. This certainly can't be done by myself on the side of the road.

Comment: @MATHBOI I see, you're caught in the system to a certain extent. My advice would be changing tires for a different brand and wider size that fits the rim. The rationale behind being that a different model could be easier to fit and since the pressure recommandations for 28 mm upwards are lower, it might also be easier to seat and inflate it roadside. Perhaps TL/hookless 25mm are just on the tight edge and it is better to run wider sizes with tubeles in general. Plus tubeless plugs to avoid taking the tire off as much as possible and good tire levers if your really have to put in a tube.

Comment: Getting punctures in a tubeless system should not be reason to stop riding even.  I wonder about the brand and amount of sealant used.  It's a reasonable expectation that the tubeless system and sealant close up punctures before so much pressure is lost that the bike is unrideable. If this isn't the case, I would try a different brand of sealant using the recommended volume (based on the size of tire being sealed).